# Периодически появляется черная полоса в Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, редактор

Android Studio. Периодически появляется черная полоса (черная строка) в редакторе. 
Как убрать? Похоже на некий баг. Помогает перезапуск, но ненадолго. Минут через пять (плюс, минус) опять все повторяется! 
Версия 3.1.4 (До 3-й версии такого не было).

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как об этой ошибке сообщить разработчикам ?

**Черная полоса в коде (закрывает строку кода, работать невозможно!):**

[image: Черная полоса в коде]

Или вот так еще косячит:
[image: Еще вариант ошибки]

Comment: Студия тоже программа и у неё тоже могут быть баги. Не знаю как на виндовс, но на линуксе такого не наблюдаю

Comment: такая же проблема, и код по-моему тот же https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48588155/black-line-over-the-code-in-android-studio-and-intellij-idea

Comment: Andrew Goroshko! Спасибо! Но разницы нет какая картинка! Картинка не суть! Суть - черная полоса в редакторе в любом месте! По указанной ссылке, увы, решения нет! Я там был до того как задать этот вопрос

Comment: а какая у вас версия студии?

Comment: Андроид Студио: 3.1.4

Comment: очень странно честно говоря, у меня тоже эта версия, и пока ничего не было такого

Comment: есть два варианта - либо переустановите студию, либо кстати вы может какое-то сочетание клавиш нажали и эта проблема появилась

Comment: Andrew Goroshko, спасибо! Попробую переустановить и над клавишами подумаю